# Enter input in an array with unknown size

Tags: java

I'm stuck on a problem where I want multiple user inputs in an array. But the size of the array is not known. What I am trying to do is that assigning the size of the array equal to the number of input entered by the user. And I don't want to ask the user that "Enter the number of inputs u wanna enter".

Comment: "*But the size of the array is not known.*" - The size of an array is always known in Java. In fact, that is your problem: the array size is fixed. I would encourage you to use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

Comment: Consider using dynamically expanding array e.g. ArrayList

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: which Turing already stated above in the more general sense.

Comment: ArrayList is a specific implementation that provides constant access just like a static array, thus I believe it answers the question better than the generic suggestion about List. Depending on what OP will next do with the container, this may be important